# JTextField no envía datos a DB mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una aplicación que estoy haciendo en java, que está conectada a una base de datos MySQL.

Creé una clase que se llama `Controlador_boton_insertar`, la cual tiene un ActionListener. En el mismo hay una función que envía los datos ingresados a la base de datos.

Mi problema es que donde dice `this.ventana.camponombre.getText()` es la unión con el `JTextField`, y no anda. Sin embargo, si lo borro y lo reemplazo por "cualquiercosa", los datos pasan a la base de datos excelentemente. Ya no sé más qué inventar. Es como si la ruta de JTexTfield estuviese mal, pero no. Revisé todo, "ventana" es el nombre del objeto Frame, `"camponombre"` el nombre del `JTextField` y  `getText()` es la única manera que conozco de capturar datos. Probé también quitando el `this` pero sigue sin andar.

```
package controlador;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import modelo.Conexion;
import vista.Frame;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Controlador_boton_insertar implements ActionListener {

public Conexion connect;
public PreparedStatement stmt1=null;
public Frame ventana;
public Controlador_boton_insertar(Frame ventana)        
{

}

private void Controlador_boton_insertar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    connect= new Conexion();
    Connection connect = null;
    String consultainsertarfila= "INSERT INTO frutas(nombre, precio, fecha_vencimiento, origen, provincia) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try{
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        connect= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productos", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement stmt1 = connect.prepareStatement(consultainsertarfila);
        stmt1.setString(1, this.ventana.camponombre.getText()); //acá es donde me vuelvo loco, si lo reemplazo por cualquier "andabien"
        stmt1.setString(2, this.ventana.campoprecio.getText());
        stmt1.setString(3, this.ventana.campovencimiento.getText());
        stmt1.setString(4, this.ventana.campoorigen.getText());
        stmt1.setString(5, this.ventana.campoprovincia.getText());
        stmt1.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Controlador_boton_insertar();   
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hola, como llamas a tu clase `Controlador_boton_insertar ` desde tu `JFrame ` , tu variable `ventana` no toma el `JFrame` que tiene los `JTextField` , solo el campo `camponombre` no detecta ? , quizá una impresión en consola de tus campos ayudaría.

Comment: bueno, entonces qué tendría que hacer? volver a declarar los JTextField y crearlos nuevamente?

Comment: Lo más lógico en estos casos es tener un `boton` Guardar en `JFrame` y esos `getText()` de tus campos enviarlo por parámetros a tu clase `Controlador_boton_insertar` y método `Controlador_boton_insertar` (no entiendo el porqué del mismo nombre) , en tu método los recibirías así `stmt1.setString(1, parametro1);`

Comment: Realmente entiendo que tu respuesta es más eficiente que lo que tengo hecho. Voy a releer tu respuesta varias veces para ver si le agarro lo mano y modificar solo lo necesario,  con respecto a lo de la clase, tenías razón, declare y creé creé los jtextfields y no funcionó del todo, pero almenos creó un registro en la DB,  en blanco,  al menos es un comienzo. Igualmente tendrás idea de porque se suben los datos en blanco?  Osea vacíos.

Comment: Como así declaraste los `JTextFields` dentro de tu clase? de que forma lo hiciste, te guarda en blanco porqué si es como imagino, luego de crearlos jamás se asignan valores, en la clase no deberías crear `JTextFields` si no obtener los valores de tu JFrame.

Comment: El nombre de Controlador_botón_insertar en la clase ,  es porque es una clase afectada por un acciónlistener,  es un Jbutton que apenas se lo toca enviaría los datos a la DB,  sin embargo quizás no fue la mejor elección   estoy tratando de entender lo del botón guardar en en jframe

Comment: Que macana, ahora entiendo un poco más el error, entonces tengo que crear un método en la misma clase jframe? Osea un void no? Que envíe los parámetros?

Comment: No, emplearé un ejemplo para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emplearé este ejemplo básico (asumiendo solo dos campos a guardar y un diseño muy sencillo) para explicar el funcionamiento de mis comentarios.

En primer lugar tendremos un `JFrame` tendrá la siguiente estructura

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Formulario extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JTextField nombre;
private JTextField precio;
private JButton  guardar;
public Formulario()
{
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  nombre = new JTextField(14);
  precio = new JTextField(14);
  /* Boton señalado en mis comentarios para Guardar*/
  guardar = new JButton("Guardar Datos");
  guardar.addActionListener(this);
  add(nombre);
  add(precio);
  add(guardar);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
  setSize(200, 200);
  setVisible(true);

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    /* Creas el Objeto de la clase GuardarData*/
    GuardarData objSave = new GuardarData();
    Object obj = ae.getSource();
    /*  Verificamos que el control que se dio click sea guardar (JButton)*/
    if(obj.equals(guardar))
    {
      /* Obtenemos los datos de las cajas de texto*/
      String name = nombre.getText().trim();
      String price = precio.getText().trim();
      /* Le envias los datos obtenidos de las Cajas de Texto*/
      objSave.Save(name, price);
    }

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Formulario();
  }
}
```

Y Una clase Guardar que contendrá un método para enviar los datos a a base de datos que recibe dos parámetros (la cantidad de datos que tomo para este ejemplo)

```
public class GuardarData {

public void Save(String nombre, String precio /*Demás Parametros */)
{

    connect= new Conexion();
    Connection connect = null;
    String consultainsertarfila= "INSERT INTO frutas(nombre, precio) VALUES(?,?)";
    try{
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        connect= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productos", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement stmt1 = connect.prepareStatement(consultainsertarfila);
        stmt1.setString(1, nombre); 
        stmt1.setString(2, precio);
        /* Demás Parametros*/
        stmt1.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: La verdad visto de esta manera es más simple de lo que me imaginaba, ahora veo de modificar todo,  porque así es más eficiente que el mío.

Comment: No sé, como cerrar la pregunta,  estoy muy agradecido porque creo que la respuesta está en los modelos que posteó dev joel.